# React Native - Making a login and register page that when valid, naviguate to the homepage

Tags: android, laravel, react-native, authentication, mobile

I have a question for you,

I have to developp a React Native application that is a social network.

My question is, how to create a login and a register page that use route to search and insert credentials.

After that, i'd like to redirect authenticated users to the Homepage of the application.

To do that I am using Laravel API.

Could you help me ?

Thanks you very much !

Comment: Heres a 2 minute video on how to create an authentication flow in react native with react navigation: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K918zJbQgug This is completely general and you can apply the logic yourself than based on which API you are using. The most popular one is probably firebase. The project in the video started of by creating a new project with "npx react-native init AwesomeTSProject --template react-native-template-typescript" (for typescript)

Comment: Thank you ! But the Flat API is imposed in the specifications.
With your answer i now know how to navigate between pages.

Now i have to discover how to login and connect with a Login and a password

Comment: Notice that you only navigate between the Home and AuthNavigator like this. Navigating between the different Screens or Navigators inside the Home and AuthNavigator will look different

Comment: okay ! But the authNavigator should appear only for authenticated users and not others, do you think this will work ?

Comment: The AuthNavigator should only appear for NOT authenticated users since you have your login/signup/forgot password/etc. screen in there. It will work and is in fact the only secure method to safely provide an authentication without users being able to skip it in some way

Answer (score 0):

How to get Email and Password on Login: (Since I answered your other question):

```
const LoginScreen = () => {
  const { login } = useAuth();
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");

  const handlePress = () => {
    login(email, password);
  }

  return (
    <View>
      <YourInput
        value={email}
        placeholder="Email"
        onChange={setEmail}
      />
      <YourInput
        value={password}
        placeholder="Password"
        onChange={setPassword}
      />
      <YourButton title="Login" onPress={handlePress} />
    </View>
  )
}
```

It would look something like this. In your login Method that you write in the AuthContext, you would than check if the credentials are correct and if so, retrieve the userToken (+ maybe some other details) and set it in the state. I can't help you further since I don't know much about flatAPI

Comment: Thank you for your help, i'm really new to React Native, Could you explain to me How the password and mail verification is done here ? And how can i affect an action (like go to the homepage) if they are valid ?

Sorry for the convenience ! (Mobile developpment is totally different from C# x)  )

Comment: I am just catching the email and password from two inputs in this example and pass them to the login function when the user confirms his information. Since the login function is connected to your backend, I can't provide you any help there, as depending on which you use this is completely different. What will probably be the same is that after communicating with your backend you will receive a userToken and maybe some other information. By setting these information into the state of the Context, the app will automatically register this and replace the Auth- with the HomeNavigator.

Comment: Well not completely automatically but its build to work like that. I suggest you pull the provided repository on Github and test the App out yourself. There are a lot of comments in the AuthContext providing steps on how you would connect the flow with your backend

Comment: EDIT : It is a Laravel API.